# Could not load assembly java.interop in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am tired of getting this error frequently. After installing "Xamarin.Forms.Maps" from nuget, getting this error message : "could not load assembly java.interop".

After searching for quite a while, I found a solution. There should be "java.interop.dll" in 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0" - this directory. If the dll was there, I could have referenced it manually. But unfortunately, there is not any dll named like this in my machine.
In this case, please give me any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBT3K.png)

Comment: Wel there is no one only reason for this , but usually in my case it is because of inconsistancy in packages. Try to update all xamarin.Forms nuget package for all the projects you have. And make sure that inside the csproj file (when you edit it ) it does not refer to more than one Xamarin.Forms package version . 
And of course do not forget to Clean and build .

Comment: Actually, I can't even update the packages. It gives the same error and can't update.

Comment: I just tried this in a new Forms solution and could add Xamarin Forms Maps without issue. Are you getting the error at build time, run time, or when adding the NuGet package?

Comment: At build time. @jgoldberger